# php Script to generate schedule

Tags: php, html, algorithm, html-table

I want to distribute some personnel in a week every day there are 3 times 7h-15h   15-23h   23h-7h .

The problem that I don't want a person to show more than one time in a day.
I want to distribute personnel list to the day of week I try this:

```
<?php
$input = array("Name1","Name2",  "Name3","Name4");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 3);


?>
<table  border=1>

<tr>

<th> Samedi </th> <th> Dimanche </th> <th> Lundi </th> <th> Mardi </th> <th> Merecredi </th> <th> Jeudi </th> <th> Vendredi </th>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php
$j=1;
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){

    echo "<td>";
    for($k=0;$k<3;$k++){

        echo  $input[$rand_keys[0]] ."7H-15H\n" ;   
        echo  $input[$rand_keys[1]] ."15H-23H\n" ;  
        echo  $input[$rand_keys[2]] ."23H-7H\n" ;           

    }
    echo "</td>";
}   
?>
```

Comment: What's a *schudle*? Did you mean *schedule*?

Comment: yes schedule but in reality I need just to distribute some personne in a week like what what I said in My question

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? Maybe you need to call `array_rand()` each time through the loop, so you get different people on each day?

Comment: the problem that I n=don't want a person to show more than one time in a day

Comment: I don't see how your code would do that. It puts a different person in each shift on the day.

Comment: I didn't arrive to that I need Your Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the second loop `for ($k = 0; $k < 3; $k++)`, because you're already showing each shift with the 3 `echo` statements.

```
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){

    echo "<td>\n";

    echo  $input[$rand_keys[0]] ." 7H-15H\n" ;   
    echo  $input[$rand_keys[1]] ." 15H-23H\n" ;  
    echo  $input[$rand_keys[2]] ." 23H-7H\n" ;           

    echo "</td>\n";
}
```

You're also using the same schedule every day of the week. So one of the people is never being scheduled for the entire week. You probably should shuffle the array each day, not just at the beginning of the script.

```
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){

    echo "<td>\n";
    shuffle($input);
    echo  $input[0] ." 7H-15H\n" ;   
    echo  $input[1] ." 15H-23H\n" ;  
    echo  $input[2] ." 23H-7H\n" ;           

    echo "</td>\n";
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/Rh6x4D)

To keep a person from working two shifts in a row if they're assigned to `23H-7H` and then `7H-15H` the next day, you can set a variable to that person, and check if the shuffle put them first.

```
$last_shift = $input[array_rand($input)];

for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){

    echo "<td>\n";
    shuffle($input);
    while ($input[0] == $last_shift) {
        shuffle($input);
    }
    echo  $input[0] ." 7H-15H\n" ;   
    echo  $input[1] ." 15H-23H\n" ;  
    echo  $input[2] ." 23H-7H\n" ;        

    $last_shift = $input[2];
    echo "</td>\n";
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/ug59Vk)

Comment: Very Nice Thank u so Much Barmer I need just last little thing   I want to be sure that the person not continu working like if one work yesterday  23h-7h  ha can not start next day in 7h

Comment: I added a version that checks for this and reshuffles.

Comment: You are realy clever Just last thing I want every one to get just one day per week for rest even If I add two person on same  HOur  like  Sidi$Ahmed 7h-15H

Comment: Sorry, I'm done, I'm not going to write the whole application for you.